# How to call a custom class from the android Application

Tags: android

I have made a new class in the android framework `CustomCall`. Now how do I call it from the android application? Because it doesn't show up in the `android sdk` since I have modified. Should I update the SDK? If so, please explain how to update.

Thanks

Comment: what is the class about. I mean what functionality it is providing. and how you want to use it. Can you put it here.

Comment: Actually I have implemented a new system call `SystemCall_new` on the kernel side. Then I am using JNI interface to call this system call. And created a class `CustomCall` I want to call this class from Android Application. 


**Functionality** is very limited (Just printing the Linux_Version). It's only **for learning purpose**

Comment: You can always add your app to Android source itself and build it